# Partial Views & Ajax (modal) Django - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-views

Two questions - I would be really happy for some advices on that. Does not expect exact code to copy - paste, but if somebody can point me to good article / course section somewhere on the infinite web that would be perfect (what`s the point of copy paste if you not learn?)

1) I remember from my Uni times (need to submit some projects in ASP.NET MVC) there was something like partial views ... they where useful to generate interface etc.

Currently my view got 2 parts (navbar and main view). My every view passing for example:

```
    template = loader.get_template('resultsetlist.html')
context = RequestContext(request, {
    'resultsets' : resultsets,
    'instance_list': instance_list,
    'latest_resultset': latest_resultset
})

return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

In this example my current view needs only resultsets object ... latest_resultset and instance_list objects are needed to generate navbar.

Template working like that:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11">
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11">
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Can I generate my navbar in some other view (name it master) and create small views to any other actions (partial ones that will extend master)? Instead of copying the same line of codes in every of my view just to generate this navbar ...**

2) I`m not hidding as I may have idea about first questions ... I`m complete green in second one (no webdeveloper experience ajax, js etc.).

One of my views using for loop to go through list of results. Let`s say every of my result got 3 attributes:
- Name 
- Surname
- Description

I`m generating table with results:

```
{% for resultset in resultsets %}
                        <td>{{ resultset.Name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ resultset.Instance.Surname }}</td>
```

As you can see I`m using only 2 fields and want to make a a button to show me last field in the popup ? This is my current try:

```
<td>{%  if resultset.Description %}
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#descriptionmodal">
                            View SQL
                    </button>
```

And modal:

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="descriptionmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-id="{{ resultset.Description }}">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {{ resultset.Description }}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I know that this have not chances to work. Can somebody help me showing howto pass data about this record (all of them in for loop, and then in table) to dynamic ajax popup that will open after clicking button? I`m ussing Twitter Bootstrap in my project**

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, since your question has two unrelated questions, I'm just going to focus on the first question.  In the future, it would be better to separate them into two questions and ask them separately (it will make it easier for other users to sort through your information).

When I'm creating dynamic menus that require queries I usually create a custom template tag.  An inclusion tag will allow you to add an html snippet with extra context, like so:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

from myApp import myModel

@register.inclusion_tag('myMenu.html')
def my_dynamic_menu(context):
    model_list = myModel.objects.all()

    return {
        'model_list' : model_list,
    }
```

Now your `model_list` will be available to your menu, without having to add it to every view. You would want to make sure you put that in a `templatetags` folder.  If you saved that in a file in the 'templatetags' folder called 'menuLoader.py', then you could access it in any template like so:

```
{% load menuLoader %}
{% my_dynamic_menu %}
```

I'd recommend reading Django's documentation on [Custon Template Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/) for more information.